# Duct tape on my range cord?

Tags: electrical, wiring, insulation, kitchens

Recently I discovered that my three prong cord for my seven-year-old range has duct tape neatly wrapped around it for about 2 inches. Is this hazardous?[image]

Comment: The tape in and of itself is not hazardous. The real question to ask is what is it covering? Unplug it before you look ...

Comment: Cloth duct tape like that isn't terribly conductive, but I don't think I'd risk not using electrical tape on an electrical cord.

Comment: Chances are at one point that was used to secure the cord to the unit for shipment. Like brhans said, have a look, but do it safely.

Comment: I'd say the tape is the least of your problems.  That three prong cord/plug is hazardous! It doesn't have a ground wire, and most likely the appliance is bootlegging ground from neutral.  Technically leeeegal, but very bad.

Answer (score 1):

Replacement cords are very inexpensive and should be available at most hardware stores or home improvement chains.  If you're uncomfortable wiring one onto your range's back panel, ask a friend (:-) -- obviously one who's experienced w/ wiring) to do it.